# Should I use U-net to label keys in a keyboard image?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, algorithm-request, model-request, template-matching

This is a 600*800 image.

[image]

**Which algorithm/model should I use to get an image like the one below, in which each key is detected and labeled by a rectangle?**

I guess this is some kind of a segmentation problem where U-net is the most popular algorithm, though I don't know how to apply it to this particular problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to draw a rectangle around each key, this is an [**object detection**](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-detection.html) or [**template matching**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) problem, so you can use any of the available models for object detection (e.g. [YOLO](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/12/27/object-detection-part-4.html)) or any technique for multi-template template matching (e.g. you can use [sequential RANSAC](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edfouhey/earlier/thesis/dfouhey_thesisPresentation.pdf) or [t-linkage](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6909900)). In the first case, you will need a labeled dataset, while, in the second case, you will need the original image and the templates (in your case, a template would be an image of a key).

So, no, this is not a segmentation problem (which would be the task of classifying each pixel in the objects of interest, and not just locating the objects).

Answer (score 1):

There are two related problems for images

1. Semantic segmentation, where you need to assign each pixel on the image some class. I.e. you have a satellite image and want to segmentate roads/forests/fields and so on
2. Objects detection, where you need to detect different types of objects and draw a bounding box for each. I.e. there is a popular dataset MSCOCO for the task, where you need to localize all bikes/people/cats/etc on the image

U-net is good for the first task, but I would say you have a second. You can use something like YOLOv3 (if you need fast inference) or fast R-CNN if you need precision. If you need really good performance, you can browse top methods for the task on the paperswithcode.com: [semantic segmentation](https://paperswithcode.com/task/semantic-segmentation), [object detection](https://paperswithcode.com/task/object-detection)